# Forced Library Column Value

Tags: document-library, column, community-site

In our Community Site (2013), We have a library that will allow the users to upload documents by category. Below is our requirement.

1. Users Select a Category from the home page.
2. Category page will display the active discussions and a Library(Same library across all categories but filters files based on the category selection).
3. When the user is uploading a document, the category drop-down shows values alphabetically.
4. **Requirement**: Is there any way that we can force the category value to default to the category that the user is on. for example if the users Clicks on category ABC from the home page, the library column should also be set to ABC when an user is uploading the document.

Thank you,
Richards.